# Database Design NBA

Tags: python, database, relational

I am new to database design so sorry if this is obvious beginner question.  I use python and sqlalchemy though I don't think that is relevant (the sample code below is psuedo code), though may be wrong. I have looked through some previous questions and didn't see this addressed.  Anyway, on to the question.  The goal here is to develop a database of NBA information which will have info on all games played and also box scores for every each player, for each game.  There are a couple ways this DB can be designed.

```
Game(game_id, date, home_name, away_name, score)
Box_Score(game_id, player_name, date, points, rebounds)
```

In this situation if I want to get all the games the Los Angeles Lakers played I can just do

```
query(Game).filter(home_name=="lakers" or away_name=="lakers").all()
query(Box_Score).filter(player_name="kobe bryant")
```

Here is the second option for how to design this database:

```
Game(game_id, date, home_name=(foreignkey=Team.team_name), away_name, score)
Box_Score(game_id, player_name=foreignkey=Player.player_name), date, points, rebounds)
Team(team_name, home_games=relationship("Game"))
Player(player_name, box_scores=relationship("Box_Score"))
```

Then I can do

```
query(Team).filter(name=="lakers").first().games
query(Player).filter(name=="kobe bryant").first().box_scores
```

On the one hand it seems like the whole point of using a relational database is to set it up like in situation #2.  On the other hand, I am not sure what extra functionality it gives me.  So I guess my question is, which design do you recommend? Are there some benefits or disadvantages to either design that will become apparent down the line which I cannot see yet? And if you recommend the simpler design #1 which does not use table relationships, why is it that I am storing a decent amount of related information but don't need to use relational database?  Thanks!!

Comment: why was this downvoted what is stupid about my question?

Comment: If you are still interested in discussing this, it's a project I'm working on and I did come up with a design but more normalized than what you had originally indicated

Answer (score 0):

The ideal data model for any database is highly subjective.  If you are new to database design, you probably will not find the ideal schema until *after* you have created your application and tested it for an extended period of time.  I would recommend reading up on some design basics, particularly [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), since you would probably benefit from a highly normalized schema, where data can be referenced in many different ways.  Highly-normalized databases can suffer in the performance department if very large (which this does not seem like it would be), but you can always de-normalize data through the use of [Materialized Views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) or other methods of caching.